# Weird errors in Play 2.2

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2

I can't make Play 2.2 work as it should.

```
//project/Build.scala
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
  val appName = "fdsfdsfd"
  val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(jdbc, anorm)

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
  lazy val buildSettings = Seq(
    organization := "123",
    version := "432432",
    scalaVersion := "2.10.3"
  )
}

//project/plugins.scala
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Debug

// The Typesafe repository 
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")

//project/build.properties
sbt.version=0.13.0
```

But here is an error

```
//Auth.scala

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.mvc.Security.Authenticated

object Auth extends ActionBuilder[String] {
  def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = Results.Redirect(routes.Application.login) //error - there is no such a method "login"
     //error: routes.Application returns Nothing

  //.....
}

//Application.scala
object Application extends Controller {

    def login = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }
}

//routes
GET        /login            controllers.Application.login
```

I did `gen-idea` and many more other commands like `clean, reload` - nothing help.

The odd thing is that it uses scala `2.10` for some reason, even so I have scala 2.10.3 by default in there and in my computer in general. Look at this picture:
[image]

I deleted `target/scala_2.10` but the error kept coming back over and over.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get url as a string by route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727315/get-url-as-a-string-by-route)

Comment: @RobinGreen, it is not!

Comment: Try to create new play 2.2 project and just copy sources from old one.